# Does any Markdown parser allow adding a linebreak to the start of code blocks?

Tags: html, markdown

One aspect of Markdown parsing has caused me annoyance several times: the lack of a linebreak at the beginning of code blocks. From [the documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax):

```
  To produce a code block in Markdown, simply indent every line of the block by
  at least 4 spaces or 1 tab. For example, given this input:

  This is a normal paragraph:

      This is a code block.

  Markdown will generate:

    <p>This is a normal paragraph:</p>

    <pre><code>This is a code block.
    </code></pre>
```

I would prefer that the output be this:

```
    <pre><code>
    This is a code block.
    </code></pre>
```

I'm not just being crazy: the lack of a linebreak and 1) causes padding to the code block to be applied inconsistently on the first line (see image below) and 2) isn't visible in my browser's DOM inspection, only by doing "view source".

---

How it looks in the browser: 
[image: actual browser output image]

How it should look:
[image: desired browser output image]

---

I've worked around this in various ways:

- Don't pad the inner element
- Post-process the HTML and add a line break

... but I'd love to just get better HTML output.

Does any Markdown parser add a line break by default or (since that appears to be non-spec, albeit trivially) allow configuration to do so?